# Modifying private instance variables in Java

Tags: java

So, I came across an example in a Java book I found:

```
public class Account {
    private String name;
    private double balance;
    private int acctNumber;

    public Account(){}

    public boolean equals(Account anotherAcc) {
        return (this.name.equals(anotherAcc.name)
                && (this.balance == anotherAcc.balance) && (this.acctNumber == anotherAcc.acctNumber));

    }


}
```

We see that the equals method is overloaded and is passed with another  Account object to check if all instance variables are equal. My problem with this piece of code is that it seems as thought we're directly accessing  private variables in the **anotherAcc** object, which doesn't seem right, but it works. The same thing happens when I make a main method in the same class where I somehow gain access to the private variables.

Conversely, when I create a main method in another class, it's only then I get  a visibility error. My question is, why does Java allow private instance variable to be accessed in a object that is passed in a method? Is it because the object is of type **Account** and the method being passed to is part of a class called **Account**?

Comment: Note that the correct way to override `equals` is to override `public boolean equals (Object other)`

Comment: I think you should see the link why we need private variables in OOP http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables

Comment: Add the annotation @Override above your equals method and see what happens..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See (my favorite table) [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass  World
-------------------------------------------
public      Y       Y       Y         Y
protected   Y       Y       Y         N
no modifier Y       Y       N         N
private     Y       N       N         N  
            ↑
       You are here
```

Since you're in the *same* class, `private` members *are* available.

As mentioned in the comments, note that you're not overriding the correct [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method. The original one (of `Object` class), expects an object of type `Object` as an argument.

Comment: He never said he was overriding `equals`, but overloading it.

Comment: I see. So this only happens due to the fact that the object passed in so happens to be of the same class, correct? This obviously wouldn't hold true for any other object type.

Answer (score 3):

*Is it because the object is of type Account and the method being passed to is part of a class called Account?*

**Yes** , `private` means not just that Object but any Object belonging to the same `class`  can access too.

Answer (score 2):

`private` restricts access to code in the same *class*, not just the same instance.